# pyodbc connect to a Sybase database in Python

Tags: python, linux, database, ubuntu-16.04, sybase

I am trying to connect to Sybase using pyodbc.

```
 conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=/usr/lib64/libodbc.so;SERVER=DBName;DATABASE=Test;UID=username;PWD=password')
```

When i execute the above I get the following error.

```
Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][SAP][ODBC Driver Manager] Unable to load resource file (-620) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I can connect to sybase using sqsh so the username and password are correct.  Any other suggestions?
I am using Ubuntu 16.04.  Not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I was using the incorrect driver.
It is a custom driver so I can't share.

Comment: I was using the incorrect driver.  I am now using the correct driver.

Comment: @user3525290 : Can you please pass across the actual driver(name) that was used that solved the issue for you?

Comment: It's custom driver.

Answer (score 0):

try this please

```
import pyodbc

connection_string = "Driver=SQL Anywhere 17;Server=demo17;UID=dba;PWD=sql;DBN=demo"

connection_object = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)

cursor = connection_object.cursor()

sql_string = "select 1"

result = cursor.execute(sql_string)

counter = result.fetchone()[0]

print(counter)

connection_object.close()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).